# LWC – Access Templates and Methods of child components (multi-chained children)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-events

Normally closed shadow DOM/root will not allow the access of child component's DOM. Consider below example:

```
<main-component>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <iteration>
                <grand-child>
            </iteration>
```

How can you change styles/add classes OR invoke methods directly in grand-child from main-component? Ofcourse you can have public API methods at each level but this will make it very complicated with many children. So, is there a more simpler and elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note: This solution works perfectly fine and much simpler for scenarios like above (when compared to public API methods). But not sure if this is valid approach - somebody from LWC development team can confirm.**

Yes! You can have simple generic registration for all elements in main-component. Then, which ever child component (in any hierarchy) has to be accessed, fire a custom registration event with appropriate details.

**Grand child HTML:**

```
<template>
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div class="my-class">
            This is grand-child component body
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Grand child JS:**

```
export default class GrandChild extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.guid) {
            this.guid = this.template.querySelector('.main').getAttribute('id');
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent('itemregister', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    composed: true,
                    detail: {
                        callbacks: {
                            dynamicData: this.dynamicData
                        },
                        template: this.template,
                        guid: this.guid,
                        name: 'c-grand-child'
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    }
    dynamicData = (data) => {
        this.template.querySelector('.dynamic').innerText = data;
    }
}
```

You need to dispatch custom event with name, guid, template and callbacks. This cannot be done in connectedCallback because in its scope elements will not be created and so elements will be undefined. In renderedCallback, we will be dispatching event only once with help of checking guid.

1. Template can be used to modify styles or add classes or any similar functionality.
2. Callbacks will have the exposed functions references
3. Name and guid are used for registartion

In child component, we can have any number of iterations of grand-child:

```
iteration = [{ mid: '1' }, { mid: '2' }, { mid: '3' }];
```

**Main component HTML:**

```
<lightning-button label="Add Styles" onclick={addStyles}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button label="Add Data" onclick={addData}></lightning-button>

<div onitemregister={registerItem}>
       <c-parent></c-parent>
</div>
```

**Main component JS:**

```
privateChildren = {};
registerItem(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const item = event.detail;

    // create key for each child against its name
    if (!this.privateChildren.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) this.privateChildren[item.name] = {};

    // store each item against its guid
    this.privateChildren[item.name][item.guid] = item;
}
addStyles() {
    Object.values(this.privateChildren['c-grand-child']).forEach((element) => {
        element.template.querySelector('.my-class').style.color = 'white';
        element.template.querySelector('.my-class').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    });
}
addData() {
    Object.values(this.privateChildren['c-grand-child']).forEach((element, index) => {
        element.callbacks.dynamicData('Changing dynamic data => ' + index);
    });
}
```

Here, you are using registerItem generic method to register all needed child elements with key as its names. Later you can use the names to access the callbacks and template.

[image]

[image]

**Reference**: https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/25/lwc-access-templates-and-methods-of-child-components/

---

**---- adding based on comments ----**

1. you are using id attributes,

> id attributes are modified at runtime by lightning framework and so in
>   documentation, its said you cannot use it for elements identification.
>   I am not using it for identification. Identification is based on child
>   elements names in parent component. I am collecting the ids as keys for `just in case`. You can choose not to collect it.

2. composed events are disencouraged

> composed events become part of firing component API. Hence we are able to access the template. Why this is a good idea, pls see below

3. you are leaking elements to higher components which should not have
   access as per shadow dom specification / design.

> As I am using `event.stopPropagation`, event will not bubble further up. So composed is fine in this case. Even if main-component is used as generic component, parent (higher) components will not be able to listen/handle the events.

1. Ordering of child components.

> I used index just for showing dynamic data in child components. But when you want to target specific child component, you can use different attributes like "data-id". Refer: https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/16/lwc-selectors-identification-of-elements/

Salesforce recommended similar approach for slots. Refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_best_composition

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96613/discussion-on-answer-by-salesforcesas-lwc--access-templates-and-methods-of-chil).