# Access child html tag: queryselector vs. queryselectorAll?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, experience-cloud

I wonder why I can't access a childs html tag via `querySelector`, I only get results while using `querySelectorAll`. I am developing a experience builder site and inserted the child via `<slot>`. So according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots) (as far as I'm understanding it) I should have access.

Here comes my example:

tabset (child inserted via slot into parent)

```
<template>
   <lightning-tabset variant="scoped" data-id="hotelbox" class="test">
  </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

parent html (ThemeLayout - see xml)

```
<template>
   <section
  class="slds-container_x-large slds-container_center"
  style="background-color: #e8f4fc">
  <div class="slds-grid">
    <!-- Subnav for test -->

    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
      <c-sub-navigation onsubnavclick={subNavHandler}></c-sub-navigation>

      <slot></slot> <-- tabset child goes into here via experience builder (drag and drop)
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</template>
```

parent xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="customThemeLayout">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>LLT Home Test SubNav</masterLabel>
    <description>Custom LLT Community Layout</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>
    </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

parent js (event is triggerd by `subNavigation`, this works fine)

```
subNavHandler(event) {
     const containerChoosen = this.querySelector("hotelbox");
     // const containerChoosen = this.querySelector('[data-id="hotelbox"]')
}
```

Doesn't deliver any results [null]. Do I really have to use `querySelectorAll` (I then receive an `Object Nodelist`) and iterate through the delivered object or do I miss something?

Note the same behavior occurs if I query for e.g. a simple `div`.

**The final goal is to use** `scrollIntoView` **with the identified tag**.

Comment: We need to see more context in the surrounding code. The description of your problem makes little sense, at least to me, which makes me suspect you're doing something incorrectly. If anything, it sounds like the bug might be querySelectorAll allowing you to query something that querySelector does not.

Comment: The selector that you have passed to `this.querySelector()` is incorrect, it should be `[data-id="hotelbox"]` instead of `hotelbox`.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you. I added more information, hope, this is describing my problem better now. Sorry for that.

Comment: @RahulGawale thank you! But this doesn't work atm. I think there is a general problem. Maybe with the Shadow DOM or my general composition?

Comment: @sfdcfox are the additional details helpful, does it make sense to you?

Comment: I think, this post [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270924/lwc-access-templates-and-methods-of-child-components-multi-chained-children) does exactly describe the intended behavior. I think I was asking the wrong things. Sorry for that.